# Can I add wildcard domain to Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console

I have just added a domain to Webmaster tools.
I realise now that it does not recognise all the subdomains.

My web app has user created subdomains. So I would like to have all the search engine information under the entire domain to be in one webmaster account.

What I can't figure out is a way to add the wildcard domain.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

it takes a while for Google to include those under same domain in Webmaster Tools

you can either wait or add each subdomain individually

hope that helps